# How recursive functions work in linked list with stack concept?

Tags: recursion, linked-list, function-call

Here I given a code to print reverse of a linked list.

fun1() prints the given Linked List in reverse manner. For Linked List 1->2->3->4->5, fun1() prints 5->4->3->2->1.

```
void fun1(struct node* head)
{
  if(head == NULL)
    return;

  fun1(head->next);
  printf("%d  ", head->data);
}
```

Can any one explain how stack frames build with each call of fun1() ?
I expected last node of linked list will print. But I am getting linked list in reverse order. It is not  making linked list reverse. It just printing in reverse. I think it is due to stack operations like Push/Pop. But I don't know exactly. Please help me to understand with the help of step by step operations in diagrams.

Comment: This question is unclear. You code prints the contents of the list in reverse order, it makes no attempt to rebuild the list in reverse order. It seems that this surprises you. Are you asking for code to actually reverse the list? Or an explanation of how the current code works?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. Your code exactly prints what it should do. Following is the code segment that meets your expectation:

> I expected last node of linked list will print.

```
void fun1(struct node* head)
{
  if(head == NULL)
     return;
  if(head->next == NULL)
   {
     printf("%d  ", head->data);
     return;
   }
  else
   fun1(head->next);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you supply the list 1->2 to it:

1. head=1->2, head is not null, recur with 2 (continuation on 5)
2. => head=2, head is not null, recur with null (continuation on 4)
3. => => head=null, head is null, return
4. => print head->data "2  " and return
5. print head-data "1  " and return

If you were to move your print statement before it recurs:

```
void fun1(struct node* head)
{
  if(head == NULL)
    return;

  printf("%d  ", head->data);
  fun1(head->next);
}
```

It would be like this:

1. head=1->2, head is not null, print head->data "1  ", recur with 2 (continuation on 5)
2. => head=2, head is not null, print head->data "2  ", recur with null (continuation on 4)
3. => => head=null, head is null, return
4. => return
5. return

In both these cases all non null nodes are printed. To only get one of them printed you code must distinguish it from the other, like this:

```
void print_last(struct node* n)
{
    if( n == NULL )
    {
        printf("empty list!");
    }        
    else if( n->next == NULL )
    {
        printf("%d", n->data);
    }
    else
    {
        print_last(n->next);  
    }
}
```

Called with the same list 1->2 you get;

1. n=1->2, n != null and n->next != null, recur with 2 (continuation on 3)
2. => n=2, n != null and n == null. print n->data "2" and return
3. return

Notice it doesn't recurse when last element found so the only way n is null is if you tried printing an empty linked list (NULL).